# How to maintain GlobalIDs while copying shapefile data into ESRI FGDB feature class?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, shapefile, file-geodatabase

I want to copy a shapefile data into an ESRI file geodatabase feature class. That feature class having a GlobalID column and it is being auto generated by the system while copying.

The GlobalID values maintained as string in the shapefile and I want to retain the same GlobalIDs in copied feature class too.

Comment: I have read this article http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000019v000000
But before that i can't copy the GlobalID string values into feature class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have followed the below steps to resolve this problem:

1. Loaded the FGDB in ArcSDE and changed the GlobalID type to GUID as
   per this [help concept](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000019v000000).
2. Created an additional string field (e.g. GloblaIDString) in that
   ArcSDE feature class to hold the GUID string while copying shape file data.
3. By using the ArcMap field calculator, GlobalIDString data copied to
   GlobalID (GUID type) field.
4. GlobalIDString field has been removed.
5. GUID type changed as GlobalID as per the same help concept.
6. ArcSDE database converted back to FGDB.

Now i have copied shape file GUID strings to FGDB's GlobalID with no changes.

Answer (score 0):

This can now be achieved in ArcGIS Pro via the Preserve Global IDs Environment setting:

```
arcpy.env.preserveGlobalIds = True
```

[Preserve Global IDs (Environment setting)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/environment-settings/preserve-globalids.htm)